# memoir: Add "part space" before backmatter chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, etoolbox, vertical-spacing, add-vertical-space

I would like the vertical space before the backmatter chapters in the table of contents to be the same as before a part. I would have thought that the code below would have resulted in this, but the space seems to be somewhat larger. What am I missing?

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\backmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpartbreak\protect\addvspace{\cftbeforepartskip}}}
\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents*
  \chapter{Preface}

  \mainmatter
  \part{First part}
  \chapter{First chapter}
  \chapter{Second chapter}

  \part{Second part}
  \chapter{Third chapter}
  \chapter{Fourth chapter}

  \backmatter
  \chapter{About the author}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE result]

Comment: I upvoted as I like the question, tried finding a solution but couldn't work it out myself, hope someone can answer. Could be worth using `\the` to find out the exact value of `cftbeforepartskip` and adding the space manually with `\pre{...}`, other then that not sure how to help!